# Looping animations using a counter (A-Frame animation mixer)?

Tags: javascript, animation, three.js, aframe

I am trying to find an efficient way to execute animations one after another after playing one animation "X" number of times.

My animations cannot be compiled into one long GTLF/GLB animation due to random animations being selected through arrays.

The issue I am encountering is repeating this code after it is completed.

Here is my current approach:

```
// Counter (to determine when to execute multiple animations sequentially)
var counter = 0;

// No. counter needs to reach. Between 1 & 3 loops
function randomIntFromInterval(min, max) { 
   return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
};

var countertrigger = randomIntFromInterval(1,3);

// Default animation for Character
character.setAttribute("animation-mixer", {clip: "animationA"});

character.addEventListener('animation-loop', function () {
  if (character.getAttribute = character.getAttribute("animation-mixer", {clip: "animationA"})){
    counter++;

    if (counter === countertrigger){
      character.setAttribute("animation-mixer", {clip: "animationB"});

      character.addEventListener('animation-finished',function() {
        if (character.getAttribute("animation-mixer").clip === "animationB"){
          character.setAttribute("animation-mixer", {clip: "animationC"});

          character.addEventListener('animation-finished',function() {
            if (character.getAttribute("animation-mixer").clip === "animationC"){
              character.setAttribute("animation-mixer", {clip: "animationA"});

            // Resets idle counter
            counter = 0;

            // Resets/randomises the no. loops before next multiple animations execute  
            countertrigger = randomIntFromInterval(1,3);
            };
          });
        };
      }); 
    };
  };
});
```

Comment: each `animation-loop` creates new listeners. Do you want  a loop of (1/3) cycles of A, and then B->C? Do you have a glitch with a simple model to test the animation states?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time `animation-loop` is emitted and `counter === countertrigger`, a new event listener is created for `animation-finished`, and you probably end up with a cascade of callbacks.

There are multiple ways of doing this, here's one take:

- keep some helpers (current counter, current animation)
- keep the logic in one `loop` callback - determining what should be in the next loop, by checking the helper values.

Something like this:

---

```
// idle cycle counter
var counter = 0;

// No. counter needs to reach. Between 1 & 3 loops
function randomIntFromInterval(min, max) { 
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
};
var countertrigger = randomIntFromInterval(1,3);

// animation helpers
var animations = ["animationA", "animationB", "animationC"]
var clipId = 0;

// start the animation
character.setAttribute("animation-mixer", {clip: animations[clipId});

// upon each animation loop...
character.addEventListener('animation-loop', function () {
  // check if idle, and should be idle longer
  if (clipId === 0 && counter < countertrigger) {
     counter++;
     return;
  }
  
  // check if this was the last animation
  if (clipId === (animations.length - 1)) {
     // Reset helpers
     clipId = 0;
     counter = 1; // the animation will be played once within this callback
     countertrigger = randomIntFromInterval(1,3);
  } else {
     clipId++
  }
  // play the next clip
  character.setAttribute("animation-mixer", {clip: animations[clipId]});
}
```